# Big Arrays and identifiers

Tags: java, arrays, identifier

```
     private Target A7; targetArray [];
```

When I compiled it, it says I need a identifier for the array size. I need to know what that is and where it would go.

Comment: It is in Java script.

Comment: Javascript !== Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error message has been truncated "si" == "size"

You need to create an Array object (Java arrays are more than just storage!) :

```
String[] answers = new String[42];
```

At least that's what you do in Java but I suspect the question is wrongly tagged;